# Ruby parentheses around arguments in a method definition

Tags: ruby

I know that many ruby style guides insist on parentheses around method arguments for *method definitions*. And I understand how parentheses are sometimes needed syntactically for *method calls*.

But can anybody provide of example of why Ruby ever *needs* parentheses around arguments for a *method definition*? Basically, I'm looking for a reason besides "it looks better".

Comment: `def a(b) end` else you would need a semicolon

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Another example is when you want to pass a hash as an argument such as to

This does not work:

```
MyTable.update_all { col_a: 1, col_b: 2 }
```

because the { } is for a block rather than a hash

Adding the parens does work.

```
MyTable.update_all({ col_a: 1, col_b: 2 })
```

In the case of update_all, it takes up to 3 hashes as arguments, so it's important to indicate  which values go into which hash.

Comment: This also works: MyTable.update_all(col_a: 1, col_b: 2)

Comment: OP asked about method definitions, so the answer is off-topic.

Comment: Hashes in that example method call are superfluous, it could be `MyTable.update_all col_a: 1, col_b: 2`.

Answer (score 18):

If you had neither parentheses nor a semicolon [as pointed out in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703024/ruby-parentheses-around-arguments-in-a-method-definition/14703424#comment20562706_14703024), it would be ambiguous.

```
def foo a end # => Error because it is amgiguous.
# Is this a method `foo` that takes no argument with the body `a`, or
# Is this a method `foo` that takes an argument `a`?
```

Also when you want to use composite arguments, you cannot omit the parentheses:

```
def foo(a, b), c
  p [a, b, c]
end
# => Error

def foo((a, b), c)
  p [a, b, c]
end
foo([1, 2], 3) # => [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: This is the first legit answer as to a reason why it may be need. I think a one line-method obviously needs it (I never use them), and the use of taking an array and the first two elements is something I've never seen. I could not even google for a definition of this, yet it works! It says take the first two elements if an array and put into a and b, or put the value in a and nil in b. It's like the mirror equivalent of the splat. Any URL ref to this one?